# Issues using Search and replace in Aptana. Any options?

Tags: eclipse, search, replace, aptana

I am having a really hard time getting use to the search function in Aptana(eclipse).

I try to search the "Workspace", which I would consider all the open files, not the whole project. But when I do this, it starts to search through the 2,900 files I have in my whole project.

Maybe it's just me. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Maybe there's some setting I can change to make the workspace choice work with the actual workspace or Maybe it's a bug. But I use the search feature the most, and it's frustrating me.

Are there any plugins, or options that can make it better, or completely replace it with something that functions normally?

If there's no way to change it, then I really think that whole search selection box needs an overhaul.  I like the ability to set up a working set, but other than that, and searching the whole project and search seems to BE a project.

I think it should have the functionality like this;

Project (all files in a project, ie: Full CMS I have)
Working Set (I have some of these - Works awesome for plugins)
WorkSpace (Files in the actual workspace, not searching whole project)
File(s) (Called Selected Resources now.Seems ok for an individual file)

The current search set up for individual or open files seems difficult, inconsistent and it's not very intuitive.  Even with a file selected, the "Selected Resources" option button is not always selectable.

I remember getting frustrated with this last time I tried eclipse as well. I was coming from (and went back to) a nice text/source code editor with a simple to understand and use search. Sometimes I can select "Selected Resources", sometimes I can't.

The "REPLACE" isn't easy to work with either. It doesn't seem like there's some sort of stepping to make the changes, It's all or nothing.

It's been about 5 years, so I am trying eclipse again for a large project, but it's a pain having to go back and forth to a more user-friendly editor just because it has a few things it does better. Mainly simple search and replace. Then having to switch back to eclipse and reloading files.

Any helpful suggestions (other than, "If I don't like it, don't use it?").

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading right you are using Eclipse with Aptana as a plugin, so this may be different for you (I am using standalone Aptana Studio 3).

If you use the Search Dialog (`Search > Search` or `Ctrl+H`) you will not have an open to search open files (the "Workspace" is not the same as open files). However, if you use `Ctrl+F` to bring up the Find and Replace view (not technically a "View"?) there is a dropdown called Scope which has an option for Open Files which should do what you are looking for:
[image]

Using this "view" it is also easy to do stepped replaces. Hopefully these things are true for the Aptana Plugin...

Edit: it looks like you can't do a replace while the scope is set to Open Files...

Comment: OH yer so awesome. I couldn't find that Ctrl+F ability for the life of me. Thanks so much.